# Select max date with given condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using `SQL server 2012`

```
create table t(dt1 date,dt2 date,dt3 date,dt4 date)

insert into t values('1970-01-01','2008-10-10',NULL,NULL),(NULL,'2008-10-10','2017-10-12',NULL),('1970-01-01','2008-10-10',NULL,'2018-10-09')
```

I need to get the minimum date from these columns, if the column value =`'1970-01-01'` then I need the second minimum date.

Below is what I tried which is not resulting correct result.

```
select *,case when (dt1='1970-01-01' or dt2='1970-01-01' or dt3='1970-01-01' or dt4='1970-01-01' )and dt1<=dt2  then dt1 else dt2
              end as DDt
from t
```

Expected output result:

[image]

Edit - I need the second minimum date, added more cases here.

[image]

Comment: according to the explanation, in 3rd row output should be 10.10.2008,right?

Answer (score 1):

Use `outer apply`

```
select  * 
from t
    outer apply (select ddt = min(v) 
                from (values (dt1), (dt2), (dt3), (dt4)) q(v) 
                where v > '19700101'
            ) q
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query works for the scenario : -

```
SELECT *, MinValue 
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(d) MinValue FROM (VALUES (dt1), (dt2), (dt3),(dt4)) AS 
a(d) WHERE d <> '01-01-1970') A
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `subquery` with `values` *constructors*

```
select *, (select min(dates) 
           from (values (dt1), (dt2), (dt3), (dt4))a(dates)
           where a.dates > '1970-01-01') as DDt
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution :

```
    SELECT * , (SELECT MIN(Dates) FROM (VALUES (dt1), (dt2), (dt3), (dt4)) AS Fields(Dates) WHERE Fields.Dates > '1970-01-01')  AS DDT
FROM [dbo].[t]
```